# OSX Mavericks Graphics issue

Tags: macos

I just installed Mavericks. Since then not only my Finder Application shows weird graphical effects.

Also I see some yet unknown phenomena in my Mail Application.

(I put some screenshots, see below)

Does anybody know about this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a problem with the new integrated graphics drivers. If you force the discrete graphics card (using for example gfxCardStatus) or by letting an application like VLC open you'll notice these artifacts disappear. It's not an ideal solution but it's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I had some serious graphics problems after I had used Mavericks for a day or two. But now I somehow seem to have fixed it. I first changed my resolution from 1440p to 1080p (when I did that my computer froze). I then started my computer in safe mood by holding down shift. After that i restarted my computer (iMac 27" i5 late 2009) normally, and changed back my resolution to 1440p, and now it seems to be working fine again.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Changing my screen resolution seems to fix it.

Comment: safe boot and resolution change seemed to work for a while, then the problem appeared again.. i'll probably try to re-install the graphics driver.. any suggestions appreciated!